# How do I change a pointer variable's value and keep the changes outside of a function without pass-by-reference?

Tags: pass-by-reference, c-strings, pass-by-value

I am doing a project for a class writing C-String-editing functions. 3/5 of the functions I have to write change the size of the char arrays I have to use, and they are being read through an ifstream input. Here is the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void stringCopy(char *A, char *B);
bool stringCompare(char *A, char *B);
void stringConcatenation(char *A, char *B);    //added const to make sure b is never changed
int stringPosition(char *A, char B);
int stringLength(char *A);
//-------------------MY-FUNCTIONS----------------------
int cStringLen(const char*);  //finds string length, but doesn't account for null char
void reSize(char*&, int len, int newLen);
void input(char*& A, istream& is);
void printMessage(const char* word1, const char* word2, const char* message);

int main()
{
    ifstream ifs{"input.txt"};
    ofstream ofs{"output.txt"};
    char* word1 = "";
    char* word2 = "";

    input(word1, ifs);
    input(word2, ifs);
    printMessage(word1, word2, "stringCopy()");
    stringCopy(word1, word2);
    printMessage(word1, word2, "after stringCopy()");
    cout << endl;

    input(word1, ifs);
    input(word2, ifs);
    printMessage(word1, word2, "stringCompare()");
    if(stringCompare(word1, word2))
    {
        cout << "They match!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "They don't match!" << endl;
    }
    stringCopy(word1, word2);
    printMessage(word1, word2, "comparing after stringCopy()");
    if(stringCompare(word1, word2))
    {
        cout << "They match!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "They don't match!" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    input(word1, ifs);
    input(word2, ifs);
    printMessage(word1, word2, "stringConcatenation()");
    stringConcatenation(word1, word2);
    printMessage(word1, word2, "after stringConcatenation()");
    cout << endl;

    input(word1, ifs);
    input(word2, ifs);
    printMessage(word1, word2, "stringPosition()");
    cout << "Searching for 'm' in word1..." << endl << "position returned is: " << stringPosition(word1, 'm') << endl;
    cout << "Searching for 'n' in word2..." << endl << "position returned is: " << stringPosition(word2, 'n') << endl;
    cout << endl;

    input(word1, ifs);
    cout << "stringLength()" << endl;
    cout << "word1: " << word1 << endl;
    cout << "The length of word1 is: " << stringLength(word1) << endl;
    cout << "after stringLength()" << endl;
    cout << "word1: " << word1 << endl;

    return 0;
}

void stringCopy(char *A, char *B)
{
    ///GETTING THE SIZES OF BOTH ARRAYS
    int counterA = cStringLen(A) + 1;
    int counterB = cStringLen(B) + 1;
    ///MAKES SURE BOTH ARE THE SAME SIZE BEFORE COPYING
    if(counterA < counterB)
    {
        reSize(A, counterA, counterB);
    }
    else
    {
        reSize(A, counterB, counterA);
    }
    ///THE COPY
    for(int i = 0; i < counterB; i++) *(A + i) = *(B + i);  //each character is copied to A from B
}

bool stringCompare(char *A, char *B)
{
    ///getting length of one string
    int counter = cStringLen(A);
    ///will move through string until diff char found
    for(int i = 0; i < counter + 1; i++)
    {
        if(*(A + i) != *(B + i))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void stringConcatenation(char *A, char *B)    //added const to make sure b is never changed
{
    ///getting length of both strings
    int counterA = cStringLen(A)+1;
    int counterB = cStringLen(B)+1;
    ///putting the length of both together for new string
    const int COUNTERS = counterA + counterB - 1;
    ///making A the size of both strings - 1
    reSize(A, counterA, COUNTERS);
    ///copying b to the parts of a past the original
    for(int i = 0; i < counterB; i++)
    {
        *(A + (counterA - 1) + i) = *(B + i);   //will override the '/0' char of A
    }
}

int stringPosition(char *A, char B)
{
    int counter = cStringLen(A) + 1;
    ///searching through string for char
    for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        if(*(A + i) == B)
        {
            return i;   //found!
        }
    }
    ///checking if b == '\0' and a '\0' isn't found somewhere before last spot of A
    if(B == '\0')
    {
        return counter;
    }
    return -1;  //not found
}

int stringLength(char *A)
{
    int counter = cStringLen(A) + 1;
    char* car = new char[counter + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        *(car + 1 + i) = *(A + i);
    }
    *(car + 0) = counter;
    delete[] A;
    A = car;
    /**
    * Will take string as param.

    * Shifts all characters to the right by one and store the length of the string in position 0.
        - Length doesn't include position 0.
    */
    return counter;   //temp
}

//-----------------------------------------MY FUNCTIONS---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int cStringLen(const char* A) //finds string length, but doesn't account for null char
{
    int counter = 0;
    while(*(A + counter) != '\0')
    {
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}

void reSize(char*& A, int len, int newLen)
{
    char* car = new char[newLen];
    for(int i = 0; i < newLen; i++)
    {
        if(i < len)
        {
            *(car + i) = *(A + i);
        }
        else if(i >= len && i < newLen)
        {
            *(car + i) = '\0';
        }
    }
    delete[] A;
    A = car;
}

void input(char*& A, istream& is)
{
    int wordSize = 0;
    int arrSize = 1;
    char c = 'o';   //checking char
    char* car = new char[arrSize];
    while((!(is.eof())) && (c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n'))
    {
        is.unsetf(ios_base::skipws);
        is >> c;

        if(is.eof())
        {
            delete[] A;
            A = car;
            return;
        }
        if(c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n')
        {
            if(wordSize == arrSize)
            {
                reSize(car, arrSize, arrSize * 2);
            }
            *(car + wordSize) = c;
        }
        wordSize++;
    }
    is.setf(ios_base::skipws);
    delete[] A;
    A = car;
}

void printMessage(const char* word1, const char* word2, const char* message)
{
    cout << message << endl;
    cout << "word1: " << word1 << endl << "word2: " << word2 << endl;
}
```

I thought I got it all done just fine. Keep in mind that I added the "&" operator after each of the pointer parameters already. Here is how they were before:

```
void stringCopy(char *&A, char *B);
bool stringCompare(char *A, char *B);
void stringConcatenation(char *&A, char *B);    //added const to make sure b 
is never changed
int stringPosition(char *A, char B);
int stringLength(char *&A);
```

But, when I got to class, my teacher said we weren't allowed to change the function headers in any way. So, I am stuck passing by value for the assignment. The problem is that I have no way of changing the c-strings outside the editing functions now. Any changes I do to them stay inside there.

It all compiles just fine, and, if I make the pointers pass-by-reference, the program runs flawlessly. I am just wondering how I could change the values of the c-strings outside of the editing functions. This assignment is starting to become a pain (so many f***ing restrictions).

Answer (score 0):

I think what your teacher wants you to do is to change the value at the character pointer instead of creating a new string.

So instead trying to reassigning parameter `A` to a new `char*` you change the value that `A` points to in memory. That way the method that called your function still points to that same memory and when they access that location the get the value you changed from within your function.